# make don't know how to make CXXFLAGS. Stop

Tags: freebsd, make, bmake

I am very new to both FreeBSD and compiling code from source and would really appreciate any help. I am trying to compile [fastText](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText) from source. When I execute the make command it returns the following message:

```
make don't know how to make CXXFLAGS. Stop
```

Here are first few lines from Makefile(complete file is available on the fastText github repo mentioned above):

```
CXX = c++
CXXFLAGS = -pthread -std=c++0x
OBJS = args.o dictionary.o matrix.o vector.o model.o utils.o
INCLUDES = -I.

opt: CXXFLAGS += -O3 -funroll-loops
opt: fasttext

debug: CXXFLAGS += -g -O0 -fno-inline
debug: fasttext
```

FreeBSD version: 10.3
FreeBSD clang version: 3.4.1
gmake version: 4.1_2

Comment: so you're only running `make` at the command line? no other flags?

Comment: which version of make are you using?
check using ```"make -v"```

Comment: This is most likely because you are using BSD make instead of GNU make (`gmake`).

Comment: both `make -v` and `make --version` do not return any information regarding make version. I guess schaiba is right. How do i find out the version of make on BSD?

Comment: I just checked the make version using the command `pkg info make` which informs that `gmake version 4.1_2` is installed

Comment: Then running `gmake` instead of `make` should do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is lines like this:

```
opt: CXXFLAGS += -O3 -funroll-loops
```

While BSD `make` honors *some* `+=` operations, this is generally a GNU `make` feature.  On FreeBSD, GNU `make` is (almost always) installed as a **port**, and its name is **`gmake`**.

You can see this on the command-line using

```
make --version
```

which prints

```
usage: make [-BeikNnqrstWwX] 
            [-C directory] [-D variable] [-d flags] [-f makefile]
            [-I directory] [-J private] [-j max_jobs] [-m directory] [-T file]
            [-V variable] [variable=value] [target ...]
```

(not GNU make) versus

```
gmake --version
```

which prints

```
GNU Make 3.82
Built for amd64-portbld-freebsd10.0
Copyright (C) 2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

(GNU make).

Most makefiles are written so that running one or another of these flavors will rely upon the `MAKE` variable being set, and (for instance) when calling successive makefiles, it will "just work".  So you can usually just do

```
gmake
```

and the rest of the details are done automatically.